# Center window (tcl/tk library) in R

Tags: r, tcltk

I would like to center my dialog created with the tcl/tk
library, but it is being impossible due to the shallow existing documentation and the low level of tcl/tk.

Basically what I'm looking for is to center the tktoplevel:

```
tt <- tktoplevel()
```

I have tried accessing the object directly, but I have no previous references.

```
tcltk::.Tcl.objv("tk::PlaceWindow", tt)
```

Thanks.